# FTP file to Mainframe server copying only first record in the file

Tags: ftp, mainframe

I was trying to ftp a file from a non mainframe server (windows machine) to mainfram server through ftp program. Input file is having 80 Record length with multiple rows.

When I ftp the file using

```
put sourcefilename 'dest.name'
```

I could see only first row/record of the file is copied. After googling i tried with following and then ftp'ed the file. But getting `250 Transfer completed (data was truncated)`.

```
quote
site lrecl=80 recfm=fb blksize=800
```

I am facing the same error. I also tried with `binary` mode of transfer. But I am unable to view the contents of the file. Could anyone of you please help me on this?

Thanks in advance!

*Note: The destination file is a GDG with new generation.*

Comment: Not programming related

Comment: @PeeHaa I havnt tagged under programming. I just want to know the technique to ftp that file. Will it leads to down vote the question? Totally un acceptable one :(

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old post but maybe someone will have some value from this answer.
Depends if you are trying to send it to the mainframe 'file system' or the USS (Unix System Services) that is running on the host mainframe system.
When You are transfering it to the USS make sure You use BLOCK transfer method + EBDIC encoding (not ASCII).
When You are trying to FTP it to the mainframe FS please take in mind that the files (datasets) are fixed size and need to be preallocated with the size. They do not grow indefinetly like on open system platforms.